# Angularjs: allow unauthorized access only for one page

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using ui-router. I am trying to authenticate all pages except sign up page.
Here are important parts of code:

In app.js:

```
$transition.onStart({ to: function(state) {
      return state.data != null && state.data.authRequired === true;
}},function(trans){
    var AuthService = trans.injector().get('AuthService');
     ....
});
```

In routes.js:

```
$stateProvider.state('signup', {
  url: '/signup',
  templateUrl:'views/signeup.html',
  controller: 'SigneUp',
  data: {
    authRequired: false
  }
});
```

But I am not allowed to go to signup page unless I am authenticated.

Comment: There's an example in the UI-Router docs exemplifying exactly your use case here https://ui-router.github.io/guide/transitionhooks#redirecting-a-transition

Comment: you need to make an exception for signup page. How about if state is signup then skip auth.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to have a service that does Authorization and stores state of current auth for any given user. From there, in each of your controllers, check for auth status, where required, allow access when not logged in; where not, make a stop gate.

eg:

```
angular.module('app', [])
   .controller('ctrlname', ['$scope', '$location', 'myAuthenticationService',  function($scope, $location, myAuthenticationService){

    //userId and Password to be bound to partials via ng-model.
    if (myAuthenticationService.authorizeUser(userId, password)){
        // DO what you have to for an authorized user.
    }
    else{
        // 
        $location.route('/unauthorized');
    } 

   }]

   .service('myAuthenticationService', ['$http', function($http){

        var self = this;

        //This is just for reference, might need more sophesticated authentication on server side anyways.
        self.authorizeUser = function(userId, password){
            return $http.get(`url/?userId=${userId}&password=${password}`)
            .success(function(response){
                //If user is validated,
                return true;
            })
            .error(function(error){
                return false;
            })
        }

        return {
            authorizeUser: function(userId, password){
                 return self.authorizeUser(userId, password);
            }
        }

   }]
```

You could define your routes and add corresponsing controllers in `routes.js`.